# Node scripts resetting ENV variables between script commands

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-scripts, ca

I'm trying to set `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` in a node script like so:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "load-cert": "export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=cert.pem",
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
```

`npm run load-cert && npm run start`

But that doesn't work (gives SSL error). Specifically, I think, because I'm loading the contract in its own separate script then running a different script/command.

#### This also doesn't work

```
"scripts": {
    "load-cert": "export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem",
    "start": "npm run load-cert && node main.js"
  },
```

`npm run start`

#### The following script *works*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=cert.pem && node main.js"
  },
```

`npm run start`

#### Weirdly enough, this also works:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
    "load-cert-start": "export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem && npm run start"
  },
```

`npm run load-cert-start`

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and if there's a way I can have a script to just load the certificate?

Comment: It's rather about bash than npm or node

Comment: I appreciate you adding the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an environment variable with `export` sets it for the current process and all child processes, but NOT the parent process. When you run `npm run load-cert`, that is a new child process of your shell. When you run `npm run start`, that is a different child process of your shell and is not a child process of the shell that exported the variable.

```
* Your shell
  \ * npm run load-cert {}
    \ * shell {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
  \ * npm run load-cert {}
```

If you combine the two commands together, as in `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=cert.pem && node main.js`, then the node process is a child process of the shell with the environment variable set:

```
* Your shell
  \ * npm run load-cert {}
    \ * shell {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
      \ * node {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
```

Or `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem && npm run start`

```
* Your shell
  \ * npm run load-cert {}
    \ * shell {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
      \ * npm run start {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
        \ * node {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
```

And for `npm run load-cert && node main.js`

```
* Your shell
  \ * npm run start {}
    \ * shell started by npm
      \ * npm run load-cert {}
        \ * shell {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}
      \ * node {} <-- Sibling, not child, of npm run load-cert
```

(Note I omitted a couple of non-relevant processes in-between in these diagrams)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I understand you fully, `run` is the main culprit, spawning new processes with `npm run load-cert && npm run start`. But what I don't get, is why the second non-working example is spawning two processes, while the second working example is spawning child processes, even though they both `run` once.

Comment: @Brother58697, Added that case to the examples.

Comment: In the last example, shouldn't `node {}` be on the same level of `shell {NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=riotgames.pem}`, as in they're siblings? Since `node` runs after `load-cert` so it becomes its child, but `load-cert` exports the variable in another child process.

Comment: No. `npm run load-cert` does not start `node`. Both are started by a shell started by `npm run start` (previously not shown in the diagram). The `&&` is implemented by the shell. Also, running after does not mean it "becomes" its child.

Comment: I was confused because in the first examples, `npm run start` and `node {}` are run as child processes after the export, and theyre also called with `&&`, so then the right idea is that `export ...` doesn't create a new process per se, but augments the state of the current process/environment, in which then the node process is started. And the reason why we can't have the export in its own script is because we then can't access and build upon that process when we call other scripts sequentially.

Comment: A good analogue that I reached from your answers is like if we're declaring a variable in the global scope, then running a function, versus creating a function (`load-cert`), then declaring the variable in it, then invoking a different function (`npm run start`), the second function can't access the scope of the first one. I was really satisfied with this, but then I'm wondering what `export` is doing. Because given its name, I'd assume, in this analogy, that it'd be lifting the variable to the global scope for the other function to access.

Comment: Generally speaking, every process has an environment block in the kernel. This block stores all environment variables. `export` just modifies the values in this block. It is not a process, but a shell built-in command (handled by the shell itself). Whenever a new process is created, it receives a copy of the environment block of the process that created it. Obviously then, changes to the copy do not affect the original. A process uses the same environment block for its entire lifetime.

Comment: In that case my analogy does fit. Perfect! Thank you so much for all of your help and explanations. I learned a lot